Explicit formula representing the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(bx+a)\varphi(x)\mathrm d x$
Let $\varphi$ (resp. $\Phi$) be the pdf (resp. cdf) of the standard normal distribution and let $a$ and $a$ be real numbers with $b > 0$.

Question. Does the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(bx+a)\varphi(x)\mathrm d x
$$
have an analytic form (perhaps in terms of special functions, etc.) ?

Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(bx)\varphi(x)\mathrm d x$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\Phi(bx+a)\varphi(x)\mathrm d x$ have anlaytic formulae given on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions.

Integrate by parts. Let $u = x$ and $\text{d}v = x\Phi(a+bx)\varphi(x)\text{d}x$. Then, $\text{d}u = 2 \text{d}x$ and (see formulas of your reference):
$$v = \int x\Phi(a+bx)\varphi(x)\text{d}x = \frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\varphi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)\Phi\left(x\sqrt{1+b^2} + \frac{ab}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right) - \Phi(a+bx)\varphi(x) +C.$$
Then, you have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(a+bx)\varphi(x)\text{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u\text{d}v = \left. uv \right|_{-\infty}^\infty - 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty v\text{d}x$$
Every function can compose $v$ can be integrated following your references.

Here is a way to compute your expression through Feynman's trick. Beforehand, let's define
the following auxiliary quantity :
$$
f(t) := \int_\Bbb{R} \Phi(a+bx)\phi(xt) \,\mathrm{d}x, \;\; t > 0
$$
The change of variable $x \mapsto x/t$ permits to recast this integral in a known form, which is listed in the page you linked, namely
$$
f(t) = \int_\Bbb{R} \Phi\left(a+b\frac{x}{t}\right)\phi(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{t}
     = \frac{1}{t}\Phi\left(\frac{at}{\sqrt{t^2+b^2}}\right).
$$
Finally, one has :
$$
\int_\Bbb{R} x^2\Phi(a+bx)\phi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = -f'(1) = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right) - \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \frac{b^2}{1+b^2} \phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)
$$

Very interesting approach. Thanks!
